# Changing the letters in a string

Tags: c

```
if (part == TRUE) {
    char finalstring;
    finalstring = *change(strfromfile);
    printf("\n%s", finalstring);
}
return 0;
```

}

```
char
*change(char *str) {
    int i, len;
    len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
        if (str[i] == "\n") {
              str[i] = " ";
        } 
    }
return str;
}
```

So I'm trying to change a string by removing newlines (\n) and changing them into 
spaces (" ").
I'm getting a lot of warnings(comparison between pointer and integer,comparison with string literal results) and the change function doesn't return the string correctly. I just get back a space and a quotation mark.

Comment: what Error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some statements in your code are troublesome and will give you warnings

```
char
*change(char *str) {
    int i, len;
    len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
        if (str[i] == "\n") {   //this is troublesome
              ****str[i] = " "; //this is troublesome****
        } 
    }
return str;
}
```

add **`str[i] =  ' '` instead of str[i]=" ";**

**You are trying to compare string literal and character--that's not acceptable**

```
char
    *change(char *str) {
        int i, len;
        len = strlen(str);
        for (i=0; i < len; i++){
            if (str[i] == '\n') {
                  str[i] = ' '; 
            } 
        }
    return str;
    }
```

and here the `*change(strfromfile)` is not needed.
 Also it seems you forgot to declare `char *finalstring` but you declared 
`char finalstring` and assigning a pointer to it that's not acceptable.

```
if (part == TRUE) {
    char finalstring;  //this is troublesome
    finalstring = *change(strfromfile);   //this is trouble some
    printf("\n%s", finalstring);
}
return 0;

}

change to 


 if (part == TRUE) {
    char *finalstring;
    finalstring = change(strfromfile);  
    printf("\n%s", finalstring);
}
return 0;
}
```

I hope this is enough. And from next time try to post whole compilable code instead of fragments. Short Self Contained Code Example (SSCCE).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
finalstring = *change(strfromfile);  /*getting error here*/
```

Does not make sense.  `change()` returns a string (`char*`), and you're just capturing its first character here.  Then you're printing it as a string (`%s`) with printf(), which if you had your compiler's warnings turned on, you would never have expected to run properly, because it's undefined behavior.  Turn on your compiler's warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) and think about what you're doing with `finalstring`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change  " "  to ' ' .

```
if (str[i] == '\n') {
          str[i] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning char * returning from function to char finalstring. function calling *change(str) should be just function(str);

```
char *finalstring=change(strfromfile);
```

Be sure that strfromfile string is **terminated with "\0" NULL** character if not strlen() and printing "%s" may also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should change char in the string you can do following

```
if(str[i] == '\n')
{
   str[i] = ' ';
}
```